# Diference between the Real numbers and a set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I was doing a exercise from my calculus class that aks for me to prove that a series converge uniformly in the set $[-r,r]$ for all $r>0$. My question is, what is the difference between set $[-r,r]$ for all $r>0$ and the set of real numbers? Naively, it look like for me that those two should be the same.

Comment: "For all $r>0$" is not referred to the set, it's referred to the verb "converge". The straightforward phrasing would be: "Prove that for all $r>0$ the series converges uniformly in the set $[-r,r]$". Unfortunately English speakers like to put the universal quantifier at the end of the sentence.

Comment: But what is the difference between this two expressions ?

Comment: The thing you're supposed to show is that the series converges uniformly on $[-1,1]$. But also on $[-2,2]$. And also on $[-\pi,\pi]$. And on $[-1114324,1114324]$. *Given* any real $r>0$, you're supposed to show that the series converges uniformly on $[-r,r]$. But just because a series converges uniformly on all such sets, doesn't automatically mean that it converges on some set which is decidedly larger than any of those sets.

Comment: The difference is that $[-r, r]$ for all $r$ means any closed interval. Even though $r$ can be arbitrarily large, that is not the same thing as $(-\infty, \infty)$. This is because no matter how large $r$ is, the interval's width is still finite. That is not the case for the entire real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform convergence is a property of not just the function, but the space it is operating on: you need to be able to control the speed of convergence *simultaneously at every point in the space*.

Whenever you expand the set you are talking about, it can only make uniform convergence more difficult: maybe a specific $\delta$ worked when you were only considering $[-1,1]$, but the function grows more quickly outside of that interval than inside it.

So, it is entirely plausible to say that you have uniform convergence on any given closed interval, no matter how big, but that you don't have uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$.

For an example, consider the sequence
$$
f_n(x):=\frac{e^{\lvert x\rvert}}{n}.
$$
Clearly, this converges pointwise to the constant $0$-function as $n\to\infty$.  The convergence is uniform on any fixed interval $[-r,r]$, because
$$
\lvert f_n(x)-0\rvert\leq\frac{e^r}{n}\to0
$$
independent of the specific $x\in[-r,r]$ chosen.

However, this does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$: no matter what $\epsilon$ you choose, no matter how large you let $n$ be, you can always choose $x$ sufficiently large to make $\frac{e^{\lvert x\rvert}}{n}>\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The point that was confusing is that I was "able" to prove that the series converge uniformly on the set of real numbers. I gonna revise to see where is my mistake.